# Excel formula results to show in another cell if true, if not true leave original content in destination cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have the current formula

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(99%,$K4)),"Will show closed next week.",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(100%,$K4)),"Completed.",""))
```

this formula will be in a column that is hidden. I want to show only the true results in that particular row on the column N. The problem is I can't figure out how to get these results to show in column N, but I don't want previous notes in column N messed with if this is not true.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is write a further conditional statement.

Like this:

```
=IF(B4="A","it is a",IF(B4="B",C4))
```

What that says is:
if [contents of B4] = "A" then "it is a" elseif [contents of B4]="B" then [contents of C4]

Or, if the contents of the cell are one thing, show this, if it's this, show the contents of THIS cell.

You can continue that sort of string of ELSEIF statements for as long as you need.

Comment: I continued as suggested. I am putting this formula in the column J cells so they will apply to each row. it doesn't seem to be calculating correctly and getting the error "something with the effect... since im trying to identify its own cell" additionally it is not carrying over the "Will show closed next week" or "completed" to the N column and replacing the existing notes. Also the $J6 in the formula is highlighted in red?

Comment: =IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(99%,$K6)),"Will show closed next week.",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(100%,$K6)),"Completed.",IF($J6="Will show closed next week.",$N6="Will show closed next week.",IF($J6="Completed.",$N6="Completed.",IF($J6="",$N6=$N6,"")))))